# How can I remotely list installed programs on a Windows XP system, while it is in use?

Tags: windows-xp

The title pretty much covers it all.  There is a Windows XP system on the network which is currently in use by another user.  Since XP only allows one active user session at a time, I cannot use RDP and run `appwiz.cpl` to view installed programs because this would result in the local user's session being locked or terminated.  So, how can I get a list of installed programs from this system remotely without inconveniencing the user?

Presume the following:

- Remote system is running Windows XP SP3.
- Local system is running Windows XP SP3 or Server 2003 SP2.
- Both systems are running practically bone-stock setups.

  - Do not presume any extra tools (MS or third-party) are installed, or non-default services enabled, unless otherwise specified here.
  - Remote Registry is enabled on the target system.
  - SNMP is disabled on the target system.
- I have a user account in the Administrator group on both systems.
- I am using an Active Directory domain account.
- I am not permitted to install *any* additional software, or enable *any* additional services on either system.
- I need a reliable list of all software which might be registered as installed.

  - The list should effectively reflect the same information which is available via `appwiz.cpl`.
  - Any form of `dir "C:\Program Files\"` is not acceptable.
- Both systems, and my user account, are members of the same Active Directory domain.
- The systems are on an isolated network, without Internet connectivity.

Comment: Does SNMP work?

Comment: Are you looking for just applications registered with Windows Installer (e.g. MSIs) or are you trying to "guess" non-compliant applications as well?

Comment: @ewwhite I'm pretty sure that SNMP is not enabled by default in Windows XP.  If I'm wrong, please let me know.  I'm fairly confident though, that it is *not* enabled on the target system in this case.

Comment: Does PowerShell count as an "extra tool"?

Comment: @jscott I'm pretty much just looking for the same list of applications that I would get from `appwiz.cpl`.

Comment: SNMP would work, if it were enabled on the target.

Comment: @Christopher Since it is not included in Windows XP SP3 or Server 2003 SP2, yes - PowerShell counts as an extra tool.  Presume that it is not available.

Comment: Verified via `compmgmt.msc` that Remote Registry is enabled, SNMP is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`psinfo -s \\"remote machine"` - and you can run it from the Sysinternals website directly, without installing it.

In your case, without Internet access, query the remote registry  (`REG QUERY`) for everything under  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` - you want terse, only extract the DisplayName value from the subkeys.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention no web connectivity.  Thanks, though.

Comment: OK, added second answer for new constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the update with Remote Registry.  I'm a bit unfamiliar with using REG QUERY on a remote system from the command line.  Could you provide full syntax, including where the system IP/hostname and other essential switches & parameters should go?

Comment: Didn't know you couldn't run "reg query /?" on your own machine :-)  `reg query \\remotemachinename\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s`. There you go,

Comment: It seems there's still so many ways to skin this cat.  I'm going to have a hard time picking an answer to accept from everyone here.

Comment: If you have WMI locked down or corrupted, my answer works and works on older Windows too. The WMI answers are better modern answers. The best answer is, don't leave the house without SysInternals Suite on a USB key.

Comment: I can't seem to get REG QUERY to work with both the /s and /v switches - the error says I'm using too many switches.  Is there not a way to do this?

Comment: NOTE:  I accepted this because WMI just wasn't working for me, and it seems additional components may be required.  `REG QUERY \\MachineName-or-IP\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s` may be a bit verbose, but it works right out-of-the-box and I can probably write scripts to pull out just the lines I need.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
wmic /node:"workstation-name" Product GET description
```

?

Comment: `ERROR: Code = 0x80041010 Description = Invalid class Facility = WMI`.  Is there some case-sensitivity I should be aware of?  Would using an IP address in place of "workstation-name" affect things?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a script for a while that works well. As suggested in other answers here it uses WMI. The nice thing is that it is ready to go. You can get the script from here: http://billsway.com/vbspage/

Look for 'List Installed Programs'.

Comment: +1 I have incorporated something very similar into my logon scripts and send the output to a log file on the server. Very handy for seeing who has what installed.